# How to debug suspected Ethernet hardware fault?

Tags: pi-4, ethernet, ethernet-port

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with 4 GB of RAM that I wanted to upgrade to a Pi 4 Model B with 8 GB of RAM. But with new device (the one with 8 GB), the Ethernet connection stops working after a few minutes. The behavior is very reliable: turn on the Pi, let it run for a few minutes, then Ethernet stops working. Let it cool down and boot it again, then the port works again for a few minutes.

First, I suspected a configuration problem, so I flashed a fresh installation of Raspberry Pi OS, did a full `apt dist-upgrade` and a `rpi-update` for good measure. But the behavior is the same.

The only somewhat helpful log message is from `dmesg` (accessed via WiFi):

```
[    9.811834] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII (RX delay)
[    9.816377] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[   45.662489] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  308.831357] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[  311.904726] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  323.167402] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[  326.244980] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  332.383449] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
```

There are no helpful messages in the system logs or in `vclog`.

As the very same setup is working with the 4 GB device, I strongly suspect a hardware fault.

Now for my question: How to best confirm this is a hardware fault? Are there locations on the board I should check for bad solder joints? Is there some other log I could check?

Comment: By the way, running `ethtool --set-eee eth0 eee off` made not difference

Comment: Did you not see the warning when you ran rpi-update? Why did you ignore it?

Comment: You mean about the risk of getting/using a testing version? The Ethernet port had troubles before the firmware upgrade and I figured it's worth a try in case it's a firmware issue. But it was exactly the same behavior before and after `rpi-update`.

Comment: I doubt this caused the problem but installing testing software only makes things worse and increases the difficulty of diagnosing problems.